# Rails API App ignores Accept-Language header value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

This is all at the Controller level, ie ApplicationController.

This is a really strange issue which may only be occurring to me.

Basically, as the title says Rails is ignoring the `Accept-Language` header value. **But** get this, order matters apparently.

So if I curl

```
curl -X POST \
 http://localhost:1234/signin \
 -H 'Accept-Language: de' \
 -H 'content-type: application/json' \
 -H 'Test-Header: Test' \
```

I can access the `Accept-Language` value with `request.headers['Accept-Language']` perfectly fine.

However, if I change the order

```
curl -X POST \
 http://localhost:1234/signin \
 -H 'content-type: application/json' \
 -H 'Accept-Language: de' \
 -H 'Test-Header: Test' \
```

`request.headers['Accept-Language']` returns nil.

Any idea as to why this may happen? I'm on Rails 3.2.22.1

Things I've done:

- Checked the Rack::Cors middleware
- Pulled out my hair
- Verified header is sent both on curl and web, also verified my findings with Postman
- Global search to see if it gets overwritten anywhere (I couldn't find anything)
- Other header values are fine. I didn't test all of them but did test custom and a handful of others.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Fix the incorrect single quote character at the end of content-type and test-header

Comment: @infused thanks, thats just a typo. I also tested with Postman and through the UI. The header value is still not accessible through `request.headers`

Comment: Only thing I found in github issues was this, might be related https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/28564

Comment: Perhaps might be related to https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9940 not sure

Comment: The header was present for me with both curls using 3.2.22.1 (or it was when I added `-d '{}'` to avoid a 411 Length Required before it even hit the controller). So the problem must involve some info we don't have...

Comment: Have you inspected `request.headers` and seen that it's not represented in any way? Or just tried the bracket access you showed in the question? It should have the key `"HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"`.

Comment: I figured it out. There was a merge issue in a pass through server which modified the headers. Making it a deep merge fixed it. Was hard to find simply because i wasn't running the pass through server locally. thanks for the help!